# Use of the noun 'associate'

Tags: style-manuals

Am I a 'former associate **at** Company XYZ' or a 'former associate **of** Company XYZ'?

Comment: I think you can be an associate _of_ a person, _at_ a company.

Comment: What examples have you found on the internet?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that's my issue, it's hard to search in Google - I'm coming up with a lot of 'Associate of Science Degree' and associate as a verb

Comment: Try "associate of" -"science" -"arts" // "associate at".

Comment: I have found: "Janet Lastname is an Associate of Zinner & Company" - although this may be ambiguous because Zinner is a person's last name...?

Comment: That would be a false coordination; 'Zinner and Company' is a compound.

Comment: Check the list [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=J_kWAwAAQBAJ&pg=PR8&lpg=PR8&dq=%22associate+of%22+-%22science%22+-%22arts%22+or+%22associate+at%22&source=bl&ots=P_OQXIGTXP&sig=cOWX4_A9J4d9zkyhTiJjjrpRNkM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dQSbVbDjJ8bn-AHzm4GwBw&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22associate%20of%22%20-%22science%22%20-%22arts%22%20or%20%22associate%20at%22&f=false) (Blau, & Lynch: either the usages are interchangeable, or there's a strange twisting of semantics going on).

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Which one is right — "He works at company X" or "in company X "?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16813/which-one-is-right-he-works-at-company-x-or-in-company-x)* Also see *[Which is more appropriate — “I work for” or “I work at”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36148)* and *[Which one is more correct: “works at a university” or “works in a university”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8656)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "associate". In some organizations, "Associate" is the name of a position (or a role), not a description of your relationship with the company.

For instance, in many management consulting companies, you will start at the company as an "Analyst" when you arrive from university, and with a few years' service, you will later be promoted to an "Associate". (I believe the reverse applies in a minority of smaller English investment banks.)

http://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Salary/McKinsey-and-Company-Salaries-E2893.htm
http://news.efinancialcareers.com/uk-en/167611/banks-weird-hierarchies-analysts-associates-vps-mds-really/

In that case, you can say "I am a former Associate **at** Bob & Company LLC" if indeed you held the title of "Associate". That is what I understood from your post.

If you mean informally, you merely had some association with the company at some point—perhaps you were a contractor supplying services to Bob & Company, or perhaps you wish to be unspecific about your exact relationship with Bob&Co, you could say "I am a former associate **of** Bob & Company". (However, I think this usage is a bit strange because a person cannot really be an associate of a corporation—you can only associate with people at the corporation.)

Comment: you've got it - thanks for the detailed explanation.