# In vs At "Place Prepositions"

Tags: prepositions, at-in, toponyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which one is right? He works at XYZ company or in XYZ company?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16813/which-one-is-right-he-works-at-xyz-company-or-in-xyz-company)

I always get confused while using prepositions. 
Should I say" It doesn't matter whether you work in X company or ..." 
or "" It doesn't matter whether you work at X company or ...."

Comment: @jlovegren Not necessarily; comments are expendable, and should probably be edited into the answer for posterity. I'll see if I can do that in a worthwhile manner. I suspect that this question and that one should be merged, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, preposition usage can often be tricky.

If we're talking about a trade etc or section of a company, we use *in*:

I worked in scrap metal / the oil industry / plastics / the financial sector // the typing pool.

If we're talking about a company / employer etc, we usually use *for*:

She works for Boots / Dunbar and Dunbar / Rio Tinto Zinc / Mr Fagin.

If we have a specific location in mind, we use *at*:

He works at the library / the sugar refinery / the pub.

However, we often use metonymy to shorten 'the high-street Boots shop' to 'Boots', and so 'He works at Boots' is also common.
Similarly, you may regard University say as the institution or the physical manifestation: 'He works for / at the University.' Note that these can have different meanings - he could work for the University interviewing candidates at a different location, or he could work (for a time) in the University trying to prove there have been improper relationships between tutors and students.

Comment: I work in New Delhi. I work in the university campus. I work in the car during the fall to enjoy the scenery. I work in the rain. I work in exhilaration.