# I work at Microsoft or I work in Microsoft?

Tags: prepositions

Which of these is correct and why?

> I work at Microsoft
>
> I work in Microsoft

I've seen 'at' everywhere but nobody uses 'in'. Why?

Comment: I work at/for Microsoft

Comment: If Microsoft were a box, you could work "in" it. Prepositions are difficult in almost any language.

Comment: I think "_in_" is generally reserved for the field in which you work (I work in the education industry) or a physical environment (I work *in* a cubicle *in* an office building.)  I'm not sure why "_at_" is used for the company, but it could also be "_for_" (I work for Microsoft.)

Comment: So we can't use in at all?

Comment: If you were standing on the pavement in front of Microsoft talking to somebody and they asked where you work, then maybe you would use  "_in_ Microsoft". But "at" is used for _exact_ locations or times (at the mall etc...at 5 o'clock)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I believe you will find the answer in *[Which one is right — “He works at company X” or “in company X ”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16813)*

Comment: As a rough guide: You work for a company, at a location, in a department.

Comment: See also : https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5411/working-in-for-at

Comment: @Dim But you can work IN a hospital/office/factory/school (also AT one of them).

Comment: @WS2. Agreed! However, while some people use IN/AT interchangeably, others will say AT can be used for a general location (inside/outside), IN actually means "inside a location" and not any adjacent territory. E.g. If you work as a school gardener, you should say "I work AT a school", and not IN a school. But if you're a teacher, you can use either IN/AT. Do you agree?

Comment: @Dim Yes. "In" does seem to convey a sense of "inside", or "indoors". However one cannot be too hard and fast, someone might say "I work as a landscape gardener in a large practice", where the nature of the work perhaps keeps them outdoors most of the time.

Comment: @Dim And one is "in the army/navy etc", never "at".

Answer (score 1):

Working "At" a company generally means working as an employee. It is not so much a preposition as "in" which refers to your current location. An employee of Microsoft would tell you he is at Microsoft even if he were working from home at the time. A contractor fixing a copier at the Microsoft office could say they were working at work in Microsoft.

I think it is more a matter of usage than strict meaning.